# How does one evaluate this variable number of multiple integrals?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to evaluate the principle value of

$\int dq_1 \int dq_2 ... \int dq_M \,\frac{\exp\left(\mathrm{i} \sum_{j=1,M} q_j x_j \right)}{\prod_{j=0,M} (q_j-q_{j+1})}$

where the limits of each integration are $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

All `x[j]` are real, `q[0]`, `q[M+1]` are fixed and real. Most importantly `M` is a variable positive integer greater than 1.

Comment: Is it $\LaTeX$?, we have it here

Comment: In order to solve this integral you may use the Schwinger parametrization $\frac{1}{A_1\cdots A_n}=\int_0^\infty ds_1\cdots \int_0^\infty ds_n \exp\left(-\left(s_1A_1+\cdots+s_nA_n\right)\right).$

Comment: Thanks but it merely turns one multiple integral to another